# In macOS, how to fix `command+option+key` changing `key` to a special character?

Tags: osx

In macOS 10.13.5 running Emacs 26.1, key presses involving `command+option` are not producing the key sequences I expect. How can macOS and/or Emacs be configured to fix this?

Examples:

- `command+option+r` produces `M-s-®` instead of `M-s-r`.
- `command+option+j` produces `M-s-∆` instead of `M-s-j`.

I'm using stock Emacs built with [`brew install emacs`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/emacs.rb).

It's interesting to note that [Mitsuharu Yamamoto's "Mac Port" Emacs](https://bitbucket.org/mituharu/emacs-mac) produces the expected key sequences. Maybe a patch is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the master branch (Emacs 27), so you could try using a nightly build of it or build it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Third, I can confirm it's working for me after building from the master branch.