# Emacs think there is an accented character in the keystroke

Tags: key-bindings, osx

Version

```
GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, NS appkit-1348.17 Version 10.10.5 (Build 14F2511)) of 2018-05-31
```

Use emacs -Q with following config:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'super)
(setq mac-right-command-modifier 'super)
(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)
(setq mac-right-option-modifier 'meta)
```

To input `M-s-a (meta - super - a)` :

use `right cmd + right option + a` , I got `M-s-a`

use `left cmd + left option + a`,  I got `M-s-å`, which is not what I expected.

Does anyone know why this happen ?

Comment: FYI you can assign keybinding to `M-s-å` to workaround this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed in the master branch a few months ago.  I'll see if I can track down the commit number and date and will update this answer when I find it.

Comment: I do find out similar info that this issue has been fixed in Emacs 27 development. https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/ao18ol/control_super_keybinding_questions/

But not sure whether it is the same issue

Comment: I'm having trouble locating the commit that fixed this issue.  Here is the original thread that I remembered reading about describing this issue right before it was fixed:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/42209/2287  Alan Third's post is dated  Jul 6 '18, so the fix is probably around there -- he is one of the most active NS port maintainers on the Emacs team.